# How to access Azure AD with Python SDK?

Tags: python, azure-active-directory

I could manage to get access to Azure resources with the code bellow:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient

subscription_id = "aaaa"
tenant_id = "bbbb"

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id="cccc",
    secret="dddd",
    tenant=tenant_id
)

client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

for item in client.resource_groups.list():
    print item

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

disks = compute_client.disks.list()
for disk in disks:
    print disk
```

But I can't access Azure AD with the same code!!! Is there a different way to access it? Why is it different?! See the code bellow:

```
graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

for item in graphrbac_client.groups.list():
    print item
```

Error:

> GraphErrorExceptionTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
>         2 
>   ----> 3 for item in graphrbac_client.groups.list():
>         4     print item
>
> /home/andre/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrest/paging.pyc in
>   **next**(self)
>       129             return response
>       130         else:
>   --> 131             self.advance_page()
>       132             return self.**next**()
>       133
>
> /home/andre/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrest/paging.pyc in
>   advance_page(self)
>       115             raise StopIteration("End of paging")
>       116         self._current_page_iter_index = 0
>   --> 117         self._response = self._get_next(self.next_link)
>       118         self._derserializer(self, self._response)
>       119         return self.current_page
>
> /home/andre/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/graphrbac/operations/groups_operations.pyc
>   in internal_paging(next_link, raw)
>       336 
>       337             if response.status_code not in [200]:
>   --> 338                 raise models.GraphErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
>       339 
>       340             return response
>
> GraphErrorException: Access Token missing or malformed.

azure-common version = 1.1.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Access Token missing or malformed.

`ComputeManagementClient` resource path is `https://management.azure.com`

But for GraphRbacManagementClient the resource path is `https://graph.windows.net`. So you got the exception.

> How to access Azure AD with Python SDK?

You could get the answer from this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/doc/graphrbac.rst). The following code is the snippet from the document.

```
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials

# See above for details on creating different types of AAD credentials
credentials = UserPassCredentials(
            'user@domain.com',      # Your user
            'my_password',          # Your password
            resource="https://graph.windows.net"
    )

tenant_id = "myad.onmicrosoft.com"

graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
    credentials,
    tenant_id
)
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. Do you knowing if it's possible gett Multi Factor Authentication (MFA) data about users? And where in this SDK?

Comment: `Do you knowing if it's possible gett Multi Factor Authentication (MFA) data about users?` Based on my knowledge, MFA is not supported .

Comment: The link does not work any more, here is an up-to-date one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/graph-rbac

Note also, that Azure AD Graph API is now deprecated and Microsoft suggests moving to the Microsoft Graph API.