# How to run a python script with packages in Azure and connect it to Azure SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-functions

I have a Azure SQL server setup that contains data from various sources. This data can be aquired through various APIs that I can connect to in python. Then, I can make a connection to the Azure SQL server in python and input the data. This all runs perfect locally, but I'm having trouble putting this system in Azure. The script should run at specific times (at least once a day, probably more) and when a manual refresh is required. To do this, one of the options would be to make an Azure function with the script and call it from Power Automate with a http trigger.

The problem seems to be that the firewall of the Azure SQL server can not be configured in a way so the Azure function has access without a premium plan, which would be overkill for a program that runs a few minutes a day. On top of that, because of a dependancy on packages, the function has to be develloped locally and then published to Azure. This means that, if the funcion has to be changed later, a new local function has to be made, the code coppied, then modified and published to Azure again, which seems inefficient to me.

So, is there a way we can configure an Azure function to have access to the Azure SQL server or is there another way of doing this?

Edit: here is the code that connects to the SQL server. It works locally but not in the Azure function.

```
    #Set the environment of the database through the url
authority_url='url'
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_url, api_version=None)

applicationID='ID'
secret='secret'
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials("https://database.windows.net/", applicationID, secret)

#Create connection string
driver='{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'
server='server'
database='db'
connString = f"Driver={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database}"

#Convert the token to a byte string
tokenb = bytes(token['accessToken'], 'UTF-8')
exptoken = b''
for i in tokenb:
    exptoken += bytes({i})
    exptoken += bytes(1)
    tokenstruct = struct.pack('=i', len(exptoken)) + exptoken
    
#Connect to the database
SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN = 1256
dbEngine = pyodbc.connect(connString, attrs_before={SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN: tokenstruct})
```

Comment: @Sampath The problem is not with the code. It works fine when run locally. It's only when the function is run on an Azure function that it can't connect to the database because the firewall doesn't allow the function. When it is run locally, the code works when it's on the right network.

Comment: I added the code to the body.

Comment: By adding  IP address  in the  networking tab of the Azure Sql server using this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure?view=azuresql-db).

Comment: Resoled it by adding the respective [IP address](https://i.imgur.com/IpYECfL.png) in the [networking tab](https://i.imgur.com/BbJyJ8a.png) of azure Azure Sql server

Comment: What was error same or different after adding ip address.share the error in chat once.

Comment: I returned the full error and the IP seems to be changing every few minutes. There should be a list in azure resource explorer, but it does not contain all IP addresses.

Comment: By adding the IP address in the networking tab of the Azure Sql server and  By clicking allow are resources. It will solve our issues.

Comment: make sure to click allow our resources.

Comment: Add the ip address , click allow our resources and save it. Also check the function network tab once.

Comment: This allows ALL Azure services and resources to access the function, not just ours. This poses a security risk, however small it may be. The IP address also changes every minute or so and the tables with possible IPs for the region the function's resource is located in is not complete as the IPs in the error message are not found in the region's IPs.

Comment: It allows only azure for resources with ip address

Comment: The ip address chages when the network connection charges

Answer (score 0):

By adding  IP address  in the  networking tab of the Azure Sql server using this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure?view=azuresql-db).

[image]

```sql
driver='{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'
server='server'
database='db'
connString = f"Driver={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database}"

#Convert the token to a byte string
tokenb = bytes(token['accessToken'], 'UTF-8')
exptoken = b''
for i in tokenb:
    exptoken += bytes({i})
    exptoken += bytes(1)
    tokenstruct = struct.pack('=i', len(exptoken)) + exptoken
    
#Connect to the database
SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN = 1256
dbEngine = pyodbc.connect(connString, attrs_before={SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN: tokenstruct})
```

By clicking allow are resoures .

[image]

- By adding  IP address  in the  networking tab of the Azure Sql server

[image]

[image]

- For More details refer Azure SQL [Databases](https://www.sqlshack.com/configure-ip-firewall-rules-for-azure-sql-databases/)  and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715948/how-to-access-azure-ad-with-python-sdk).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this does not work. Even when the IP adress is added, it does not work.

Comment: @Wannes make sure to click allow our resources.

Comment: This allows ALL Azure services and resources to access the function, not just ours. This poses a security risk, however small it may be. The IP address also changes every minute or so and the tables with possible IPs for the region the function's resource is located in is not complete as the IPs in the error message are not found in the region's IPs.

Comment: It allows only azure for resources with ip address.The ip address chages when the network connection charges .